# Is the Movies and TV Stack Exchange site the best for asking about music videos?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm not sure would a music video quite fit in with the theme Movies and TV but then again there isn't another site I could see that would be more related.

So I'm wondering is this site the best for asking about music videos?
If not then which Stack Exchange site would be best?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Music Video is a bit of a grey area, but if the question is primarily about the video - story, themes, acting, cast etc, then it would probably be on topic.  If it is primarily about the music or the artist, then probably not.

I can think of examples of music video which would clearly (IMHO) be on topic, for example [Cloudbusting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloudbusting) by Kate Bush tells a story of Willhelm Reich and son making a rain making machine, and stars Donald Sutherland and Terry Gilliam was involved in the creative process.

On the other extreme, a music video just involving the band playing the song is less interesting to the community here and a question would risk down voting at the very least.

If the question is more about AV production techniques, then the [Audio Visual Production](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-video-production) beta site may be more suitable.

Comment: Just like Movies&TV, I think there should be a site for Music - videos, chords, tunes, lyrics, etc. There seems to be only one which is more for musicians and creators of music.