# What do you think of this music video question?

Tags: discussion

In a couple of previous discussions it seems that Music Video questions are a very grey area, and indicated [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289/music-videos-on-topic) and [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/512/is-the-movies-and-tv-stack-exchange-site-the-best-for-asking-about-music-videos).

I recently came up with a question about a music video I had watched.  The music video was The Offspring's video Hammerhead (will add video link when I can).  In this video there's quite a bit of imagery that I just don't flat out understand the importance of.  I'd like to ask something along the lines of **what is the meaning of the imagery in this video**.

Another video that I find somewhat confusing is Slipknot's Snuff (again, link later).  I'd like to understand what the story in the video is supposed to be about.

Do these sort of questions seem like they would be acceptable, or do our members not like the idea of letting questions like this on the site?

Comment: Re-evaluating what has been previously said is my stance.  Long as it can apply more to the imagery rather than the music, it should be fine.

Comment: The only issues might arise from the answers which, unless somebody turns up concrete evidence to the contrary, could fall into the purely subjective range. See my answer for instance ;)

Answer (score 5):

There has never been a length requirement for what constitutes a "film" on the site, and if we consider a music video to be a short film, I don't see it as being a problem ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_video) via an essay by a critic named Dan Moller backs me up on this, "A music video or song video is a short film integrating a song and imagery, produced for promotional or artistic purposes.").

So, based on that and the other opinions aired in the Meta questions you linked, I'd say your questions would be solid additions to the site.  Certainly if abuses/edge cases pop up, these issues can be revisited.